# Does anyone know of a tutorial for datamapper + sqlite3 with ruby?

Tags: ruby, database, relational-database, datamapper

I'm a newbie to programming & ruby (as well as datamapper & sqlite).  I'm trying to figure out how to use all three but can't find any tutorials for beginners.

Please let me know of tutorials or books.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Both cheatsheet and the blog post are a bit out of date. I'd suggest looking here:

http://datamapper.org/getting-started

and then go through the official docs too:

http://datamapper.org/docs

If you have any issues you can always find help on #datamapper irc channel

Answer (score 1):

http://snippets.rorbuilder.info/posts/show/784

and a cheat sheet:

http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/datamapper/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply...both are great resources.